# How do I simply refer to an instance in terraform?

Tags: terraform

Consider the following resource:

```
resource "type" "myspecialresource"
{
   for_each = toset(["some thing", "some other thing"])
}
```

What do I need to add to this resource to be able to refer to it by string later on?

So, for example, I know to reference the second instance of this resource later on I can do:

`type.myspecialresource[1]`, but I'd like to reference it like so instead:

`type.myspecialresource["some thing"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type.myspecialresource["some thing"]` **that's how it will work**. `type.myspecialresource[1]` is for when you use `count`. Since you are using `for_each`, you have to use `type.myspecialresource["some thing"]`.

Comment: I think I was overthinking this before even trying it! Thanks

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ No problem. Glad I could clarify that.